# Umbraco Package (ImageProcessor) Crashing site

Tags: package, umbraco, imageprocessor

So I tried to install a package called 'Image Processor' to our Umbraco build which I later found was incompatible. How do I manually remove this package from the build? I've tried removing all mention of 'ImageProcessor' from the Web.config, packages.config etc still no cigar.

This is the error we're getting.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check in the `/bin/` folder for the Image Processor DLL file. If this file is present, I believe that the application is trying to load it. However, this file requires something from `Umbraco.Core` which isn't there, so it crashes.

If you find the DLL, try deleting it and reloading the application.

Also, I assume you installed this package through Umbraco. In the future I would recommend using NuGet to install packages, as it allows you to add, update and remove packages without running the application (so if you were to get an error like this again, you would be able to easily uninstall the package).

Comment: Hey Harvey,

I deleted the ImageProcessor.dll files in /bin/ which I believe there were 3. Not sure how to deal with the Umbraco.Core.dll if there is something in there that needs to be removed. The error does seem to be referencing the Umbraco.Core file as the point of the error.

You're right I did install this through Umbraco however I installed this on a test server and my local environment is slightly different. (I know really stupid!)

Comment: If your local is still working, you should redeploy all of your local DLLs to the server. That should sort out the dependencies.

Comment: Hi Harvey that did the trick. So I copied my local /bin/ folder over to the corrupted build and it brought it back to life. I made sure to remove all mentions of the plugin as well from all the files in there. I then refreshed the Umbraco Cache once I knew it was clear and it was back to normal again!